# How to update default values of reactive() in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am building an app with Nuxt 3 and using Composition API with async data. Here is the situation: I have a page that will contain articles which data is fetched from the database via `useLazyFetch()` and each article page is in one single file named `projects/[project].vue`.

Here `projects/[project].vue`:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute();
const projectName = route.params.project;
const { pending, data } = useLazyFetch("/api/project", { params: { name: projectName } });
const state = reactive({
  title: data.value?.project?.title ?? '',
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ state.title }}</h1> 
    <input v-model="state.title" />
  </div>
</template>
```

It works fine, but when I go back to my main page to chose a different article, the **data remains the same**. Therefore, the content of the first visited article stays whereas I would like the `state` to get the value of the new visited article. Indeed, it is conserved despite the navigation between pages.

> **NOTE**: `data.value.project` can be null.

I tried to enforce it with `refresh`:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRouter();
const projectName = route.params.project;
const { pending, data, refresh } = useLazyFetch("/api/project", { params: { name: projectName } });
const state = reactive({
  title: data.value?.project?.title ?? '',
});

watchEffect(async () => {
  if (!pending.value && data.value.project != null) {
    if (projectName !== data.value.project.id) { // it means the current data doesn't belong to the project selected in the URL
      await refresh(); // this doesn't refresh the state... I don't even know if it's useful
    }
  }
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ state.title }}</h1> 
    <input v-model="state.title" />
  </div>
</template>
```

This method doesn't change anything.

> **NOTE**: using `ref` instead of `reactive` doesn't change anything either.

> **NOTE**: using `useFetch` doesn't work either.

> **NOTE**: using `useLazyAsyncData` doesn't work either.

To sum up, how do I update the default values of `reactive()` using Composition API.

Answer (score 0):

watchEffect runs immediately on component creation and any time it's dependencies change.  I'm not familiar with `refresh()` but why not move
`{ pending, data} = useLazyFetch(...)` and update state directly in the watchEffect?  similar to this example in the Vue [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect)

```js
watchEffect(async (onCleanup) => {
  const { response, cancel } = doAsyncWork(id.value)
  // `cancel` will be called if `id` changes
  // so that previous pending request will be cancelled
  // if not yet completed
  onCleanup(cancel)
  data.value = await response
})
```

Comment: With SSR it would not generate a page with the data, which i need for SEO.